# Javascript update function via change src script file

Tags: javascript, function, updates

My javascript file with function:

scr.js:

```
function myf(){
    alert('aaa');
}
myf();
```

After load page, I see dialog box with 'aaa'. This is right.
The next, I change script source to:

```
function myf(){
    alert('bbb'); ///////////
}
myf();
```

and src file by add to him timestamp (for update file):

```
$('script[src^="./scr.js"]').attr('src','./scr.js?='+new Date().getTime());
```

The problems:

1. after update file, the myf() function doesn't run.
2. after run myf() function from browser console I see dialog with 'aaa' not with 'bbb'
3. when I remove script tag with src scr.js, I can call again my function

Where is problem and what do for update scritpt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As far as I know, changing a script src attribute, doesn't force the browser to download the script; you need to create a new script tag and append it to the DOM.
2. Because the browser didn't downloaded and executed the new script.
3. When your script was first run by the browser it created a global function, which has been attached to the global object; that's why you can still call it, even though you've dinamically removed the script.

UPDATE (Possible solution):

1. Create a script element dinamically using something like this:

```js
function createScript(src) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = src;
    return s;
}
```

2. Update the DOM:

```js
var oldScript = document.querySelector("script[src^='s.js']");
var newScript = createScript("s.js?t=" + (new Date()).getTime());
document.body.replaceChild(newScript, oldScript);
```

(you can translate that into jQuery if you want)

Comment: Yeah!  The secret is in remove older script tag, and add new. The same updating src doesnt updating script. Thank You!